# JMeter JSON Extractor to get value by conditions

Tags: json, jmeter, extract

I would like to extract the Name where the RoleId = 4 and the OwnerType = "Client". So, for the following JSON string, I should get "CLI_100117057". I have googled a lot and tried a lot. But none of my Json expression works.

Any help would be appreciated

```
{"d":{"result":{"result":[{"PersonOrGroupRoleTypes":[{"RoleId":4,"RoleInheritance":"NotInherited","SecurityGroupId":155},{"RoleId":22,"RoleInheritance":"FirmWide","SecurityGroupId":155}],"OwnerType":"Internal","Name":"INT_100044373"},{"PersonOrGroupRoleTypes":[{"RoleId":4,"RoleInheritance":"NotInherited","SecurityGroupId":155},{"RoleId":22,"RoleInheritance":"FirmWide","SecurityGroupId":155}],"OwnerType":"Client","Name":"CLI_100117057"},{"PersonOrGroupRoleTypes":[{"RoleId":22,"RoleInheritance":"FirmWide","SecurityGroupId":155}],"OwnerType":"Client","Name":"CLI_100119370"}]}}}
```

Comment: Show what you tried

Comment: Have you tried approachlike Ex $.d.result.result[?(@.OwnerType == 'Client')].Name

Comment: Yea, $..result[?(@.OwnerType == 'Client')].Name can find Name where ownertype = client. But I need something like : $..result[?(@.OwnerType == 'Client' && @.RoleId == 4)].Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators) in order to limit the output to only the values you're interested in:

```
$.d.result.result[?(@.OwnerType=='Client' && @.PersonOrGroupRoleTypes[0].RoleId==4 )].Name
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter/)

Comment: Works! Thank you Dmitri. Appreciated.